# Qual linguagem estudar?

Tags: php, java, .net

Seguinte pessoal, estou fazendo o 2º semestre do curso de Sistema de Informação e estou em uma grande dúvida de qual linguagem me dedicar para aprender!

Gostaria de saber qual foi a primeira linguagem que vocês aprenderam e qual é a mais aceita no mercado do norte e nordeste?

Comment: Estou sinalizando para fechar, porque, como a primeira resposta já diz: "É baseado na minha opinião.". Essa pergunta vai muito de opinião das pessoas, pode ter seu escopo reduzido, tornando-a um pouco mais objetiva, mas, ainda sim, linguagens são passageiras e nunca teremos uma resposta definitiva em qualquer escopo. :/

Comment: @LucianoOliveiraLima veja se é possível dentro do que você procura saber e reformule a pergunta para algo mais específico que da para aproveitar sua pergunta , por  exemplo salário de programador Java ou .NET, ou qual é mais usado etc. No sentido de usar uma "métrica" ai poderemos dar indicadores melhores do que uma simples opinião

Answer (score 2):

Isso vai depender bastante de suas necessidades. Se você tem interesse em desenvolver para WEB, PHP é uma linguagem bastante fácil para aprender.
Se for seguir com o PHP, recomendo muito você estudar algum framework:

Codeigniter: Alta curva de aprendizagem, MVC bastante simples e por isso é bastante versátil. Com bom conhecimento você pode modifica-lo pra te atender melhor. Recomendado pra sites.

Cakephp: Também um framework famoso e simples. Possibilita a criação de aplicações simples ou mais complexas. Fácil de aprender e tem uma comunidade grande.

[Laravel](http://laravel.com/): Esse é o nome da vez, é um framework MUITO bom, mas ao mesmo tempo complexo pra quem está aprendendo. Recomendo apenas quando você estiver mais familiarizado com PHP OO e MVC.

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/): Esse sem dúvidas é o mais completo de todos. É desenvolvido pela mesma equipe que cuida do PHP. É um framework para aplicações robustas. A curva de aprendizagem é longa, então recomendo apenas para quem já tem um certo conhecimento com PHP e MVC.

Sobre as outras linguagens (JAVA, .NET) não posso te falar pois não tenho experiencia com elas. Mas o que posso te afirmar é que, uma vez você entendo conceitos de programação e lógica, as linguagens se tornam apenas ferramentas pra você e isso é o que importa, resolver problemas.

Answer (score 2):

Posso ser criticado( e vou ) mas, é a minha opinião e peço apenas para que respeitem o meu ponto de vista.

Ao me ver, para quem esta começando a estudar uma linguagem o foco deve ser "aprender" e partindo deste ponto eu excluiria o .NET como linguagem para iniciar os estudos, linguagens com maior numero de pessoas para te ajudar é o recomendado e isso você irá encontrar em maior quantidade no **PHP e Java**, pronto falei, quem não gostou da -1, mas é o MEU ponto de vista.